# Comando find no tiene el flag "-printf"

Tags: macos, find

estoy intentando listar todos los ficheros .sh a partir de la ruta principal desde donde se llama el script, de tal forma que solo me quede el nombre de cada archivo (sin extension) y con un salto de línea al final. Este es el scrip que tengo:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/\.sh$//'
```

Pero no funciona. He investigado y resulta que -printf no funciona en Mac, y no sé que más hacer porque la búsqueda se hace en el directorio principal y en TODOS los subdirectorios, entonces hacer una simple sustitución no me sirve pues las rutas son variables. Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

##### Puedes instalar el `find` de GNU usando `brew`

- `brew install findutils`
- A partir de aquí, llámalo con `gfind`

##### Puedes usar `print0` para escribir el nombre del archivo

- `find . -print0`

##### Puedes usar `-exec stat` para imprimir la info del archivo que quieras:

- `find . -exec stat -c "..." {} \;`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, el primer caso no lo puedo usar pues debo hacer sin instalar paquetes externos. En el segundo, lo pruebo pero me imprime la ruta entera, y yo quiero quitar toda la ruta completa y solo dejar el nombre del archivo. La tercera opción que me propones tampoco me lo corrige, y la verdad no entiendo el error pues me dice que falta un ";" o "+" al final de stat. Perdón por mi torpeza, no he trabajado mucho con Mac y menos con el intérprete de comandos

Comment: Puedes usar por ejemplo `find . -type f -name '*.sh' -exec stat -f%N {} \;` para que te dé el nombre del archivo